# Copy Excel from Source to Destination

Tags: python, excel, shutil

I am trying to copy excel files that start with XXXXX in a source directory and put them into a destination directory that matches the first XXXXX of the excel file. I would also only like to match the first XXXXX of the folder in destination. After the file is then put into the destination folder I want to changes the name. The below code only allows me to drop the src excel into a folder named only XXXXX not ( e.g. 'XXXXX FOLDER') and it only renames the file in the root directory. thoughts?

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_src):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
            filename = file[:5]
            shutil.copy((dir_src +'\\'+file), (dir_dst + '\\'+ filename))
            for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_dst + '\\'+ filename, '*.xlsx')):
                    os.rename(filename, 'Weekly_Claims.xlsx')
```

Comment: Could you add an example, like the excel file with this name should end up in this folder? I am not sure what you want the final directory structure to be like

Comment: I want the excel file 00000_Services.xlsx to put into dir_dest folder that matches the excel slightly. '00000 James Joyce'. So I want to loop through the excel files all silimar in their style (e.g. 00001_ Services to match to then '00001 Hunter S. Thompson') basically given the first 5 char of the src file I want to copy it to a matching string folder in dir_des subfolder and put it into their. so 00000 matches the full 00000 James Joyce folder and copies only excel file 00000_Services.xlsx into it.  Does that help? Also all these folder in dir_des are already created.

Comment: @EdgarH if this is too verbose I can DM or email? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out... Though someone out there might have a more pythonic way of doing it

```
import glob,os   
import shutil
import re

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_src):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
            filename = file[:5]
            src_file = os.path.join(dir_src, file)         
            #search destination subdirectory for folder 
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(des_test):
                for name in dirs:
                    #if the source filename equals first 5 of the subdirectory name, copy to the des_file
                    if filename == name[:5]:
                        dst_file = os.path.join(des_test, name)
                        shutil.copy(src_file, dst_file)
```